# Find all duplicate rows in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to be able to get the indices of all the instances of a duplicated row in a dataset without knowing the name and number of columns beforehand. So assume I have this:

```
     col
1  |  1
2  |  2
3  |  1
4  |  1
5  |  2
```

I'd like to be able to get `[1, 3, 4]` and `[2, 5]`. Is there any way to achieve this? It sounds really simple, but since I don't know the columns beforehand I can't do something like `df[col == x...]`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First filter all [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) rows and then  [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with `apply` or convert `index` [`to_series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.to_series.html):

```
df = df[df.col.duplicated(keep=False)]

a = df.groupby('col').apply(lambda x: list(x.index))
print (a)
col
1    [1, 3, 4]
2       [2, 5]
dtype: object
```

---

```
a = df.index.to_series().groupby(df.col).apply(list)
print (a)
col
1    [1, 3, 4]
2       [2, 5]
dtype: object
```

And if need nested lists:

```
L = df.groupby('col').apply(lambda x: list(x.index)).tolist()
print (L)
[[1, 3, 4], [2, 5]]
```

If need use only first column is possible selected by position with [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
a = df[df.iloc[:,0].duplicated(keep=False)]
      .groupby(df.iloc[:,0]).apply(lambda x: list(x.index))
print (a)
col
1    [1, 3, 4]
2       [2, 5]
dtype: object
```

Comment: Okay that's good, except that since I don't know the columns I need to groupby df.columns, but that's fine. I don't know how I didn't think of groupby by myself.

Comment: I add solution for select by position.

Comment: Can this find duplicate rows with multiple columns too? I mean I see only **col** in the example not **col1**, **col2**, **col3**, and so on.

Comment: @nabin For check dupes in multiple columns use `df = df[df.duplicated(subset=['col','col1','col2'], keep=False)]`, if want check dupes by all columns `df = df[df.duplicated(keep=False)]`

Comment: This is just what I needed